# Setting limits in an if function?

Tags: python, if-statement, currency

On line 14, I want to notify the user that their account is overdrawn. I want this to appear when they have withdrawn **up to** 50 more than their current balance. If they go over this the withdrawal will be refused.

```
bal = input("What is your account balance?:            ")
intbal = int(bal)

withdraw = input("How much would you like to withdraw?:     ")
intwith = int(withdraw)

max = intbal + 50

if intwith <= intbal:

    print()
    print("Withdrawal successful. Current balance:   ", intbal - intwith)

elif intwith >= intbal or max:

    print()
    print("Withdrawal successful, the account is overdrawn. Current balance:        ", intbal - intwith)

elif intwith > max:

    print()
    print("Withdrawal refused, insufficient funds. Current balance:", intbal)

else:

    print("Invalid input")
```

I tried using "or" which clearly did not work. What are some solutions?

Comment: Python can do chained greater-than/less-than comparisons: `elif intbal <= intwith <= max:`

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is a pretty good first question but there are a fair amount of rules for posting on the site.

Answer (score 2):

##### solution

In Python you can [chain comparisons](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/).

Change the line 14 to.

```py
elif max >= intwith > intbal:
```

##### why your expression on line 14 always evaluates to True

If statement in python uses 'magic' `__bool__()` method ([python documentation on __bool__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__bool__#object.__bool__)) to evaluate, whether the expression is True or False. For integer, this is True if `int != 0`. So your expression is equivalent to `elif intwith >= intbal or max != 0:`. As the `max` variable is not `0`, it clearly always evaluates to True.

Answer (score 1):

The or statements combines two booleans. You are just saying or max, and since max (you should use another name since max is an inbuilt function) is not 0 it is seen as true. So your statement always reads as "x or True". Instead you should do:

```
elif intwith >= intbal and intwith <= max:
```

Comment: Unlike most languages Python can do chained comparisons, see my comment or the other answer.

Comment: Yes you can but you don't have to. I thinks it is easier to read and easier to adjust this way